# OK to fill a tree trunk with soil and plant in it?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, tree-care, succulents

We have an old apricot tree where the trunk sustained unknown damage (It was here when we bought the house, so we don't know what happened to it, specifically) and is mostly hollowed out:

[image: Hollowed out apricot tree trunk]

Surprisingly, the tree is still alive and sprouts leaves, flowers, and even some fruit every year.

I came across this idea for planting plants inside an old tree:

[image: Succulents in an old tree]

I realize that the tree will probably have a substantially shorter life due to the damage, but would filling the cavity with soil and planting plants in it be *even worse* for the tree?  Or won't it make any difference?

Comment: I would let Nature take it’s Course and the Extra Foliages if needed would look extraordinary growing in the split Hollows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I note that your example is evidently quite dead (no bark at all,) while your tree is still alive and fruiting.

To the best of my knowledge, filling the cavity of a living tree with dirt and plants will indeed accelerate its demise. One suggestion would be to plant pits from the apricots it produces to develop a new tree (if you like them and want that part to continue) and then the (inevitable, whether accelerated or delayed) demise of the parent tree will be less of an issue when it comes.